# Question deleted, can't recreate new one

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-questions

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529361/how-to-have-sonnar-runner-running-when-sources-are-on-another-server) on sonar yesterday and then deleted it because it was not clear enough, as I wasn't able to edit it properly.

Today I want to post a question on the same subject but I can't. It keeps telling me I already posted a similar question.

When I follow the link to my question I'm told it was removed by the author which is me.

Comment: That is strange, but this might be by design. I've flagged a moderator to undelete the answer.

Comment: @Asad Question I assume?

Comment: @Bart Yup, sorry.

Comment: Wallou, can you still see the question's content? Can't you simply undelete it?

Comment: @Bart Users under 10k cannot undelete their questions and this is by design apparently.

Comment: The question is now undeleted

Comment: Thanks for undeleted it.

Comment: @Rapptz D'oh....I should really start asking questions on SO one of these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of asking the same question again, you should edit your previous question and improve it. To undelete your question flag one of your post with that deleted question's link. Once moderators undelete your question, edit and improve it.

And the question is undeleted now.

Comment: It might not necessarily need improvement, since it was deleted a minute after it was posted by the OP.

Comment: I wasn't able to edit the question. Whatever changes i made it wasn't updated properly.

Comment: @Asad - True. But by reading *improve it*, someone may improve the question. :)